# "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy haciendo una servicio rest con java jpa spring boot. Las tablas se crean correctamente en la base de datos y probando localmente todo funciona correctamente, pero cuando monto el .war en un tomcat en mi vps, empieza el fallo.

Al hacer una petición POST a /oatuh/token para iniciar sesión me lanza una excepción:

> "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi entity usuario:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "users")
 public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7125479784396028079L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username", unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email", unique = true)
private String email;
```

El DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>{

@Query("select u from UserEntity u where u.username = ?1")
public UserEntity findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Y el service:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserEntity user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
    System.out.println(user);

    if (user == null) {
        log.error("El usuario no existe en la base de datos.");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario inexistente en la base de datos");
    }

    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, null);
 }
```

Comment: Que estas usando como base de datos? asegurate de estar conectado ala base de datos y dependiendo de si es un server tu query prodia tomar un cambio

Comment: Como te indica @daniel-angel, esto tiene pinta de no estar conectado. Podrías revisar si la conexion a la BD es exitosa (o añadir los logger correspondientes para que puedas saberlo).